# How to integrate Sugarcrm with google calendar.?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, sugarcrm

I'm using sugarCRM CE 6.5.14.

I planned to integrate sugarcrm task with google calendar.

Based on this link, I've configured my google calendar.

https://www.upcurvecloud.com/blog/sugarcrm/adding-a-sugarcrm-calendar-to-your-google-calendar/

At present, the SugarCRM scheduled tasks are updated after 24 hours into google calendar.

I googled but the details are/were not enough to complete my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use that service - https://cloudwork.com/integrations/google-calendar/sugarcrm?utm_source=google_calendar&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=vendor_marketplace
For me it's work!